# org-mode Widen All of It

Tags: org-mode, narrowing

Whenever I open an org file in a specific way, it sort of opens it narrowed, not displaying all of its content.

I've tried the widen function, but that only works after narrowing it;)

What I do, is go to the top level, then TAB twice and it's all back to normal, but then I'm lost as to where I came from;)

What is the command to load the whole file at all times and is there maybe a default to load the entirety at all times?;)

Comment: A specific Org mode file or all Org mode files? For a single file, you might have specified a `#+STARTUP: ` option that causes that. If it happens for all Org mode files, you might have customized `org-startup-folded`. If neither is the case, then the default is to show everything. See [Initial visibility](https://orgmode.org/manual/Initial-visibility.html) in the manual. Also, what do you mean by opening the file "in a specific way"?

Comment: BTW, the usual term is `folding` - `narrowing` is a different mechanism for showing only part of a buffer.

Comment: plz be more specific about your "specific way", but I have a hunch that what you want is "C-u C-u C-c C-r"

Comment: You can get the value of `org-startup-folded` in a particular buffer with `C-h v org-startup-folded`. What value do you get in the troublesome example? Now start with `emacs -q` and do the same thing: what value do you get?